# VBA PowerPoint Table Cell's Format

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have been looking everywhere for this solution but can't seem to find it anywhere.
I want to access these offsets percentage  of the cell so I can make the image smaller

[image]

But when I use this code

```
With $SHP.Table.Cell(1, $i).Shape.Fill  
  .TextureOffsetX = 25  
  .TextureOffsetY = 25
Endwith
```

This happens:

[image]

Texture tile turns to true and my picture is being repeated itself.

Comment: That's a _chart_, not a table. The controls in your screen shots are for adjusting the tiling of pictures inserted as backgrounds. The VBA you have listed is doing exactly what it's supposed to.

Comment: There is a table below the chart... @JohnKorchok

Comment: Have you tried to change 25 to 25%? .TextureOffsetX = 25% or something

Comment: Yep does not work that way unfortunately!

Comment: The only way to place images in a PowerPoint table is to set them as the cell background. The image will always or shrink to fit the cell. So you need to change the size of the cells to change the image size. Changing the offsets will not do it.

Comment: Many images have different dimensions so that wont do. Changing offsets really does the trick but as I can see noone has ever accesses offsetTop (carefull not Offset X or OffsetY) I am talking about Offset Top, Bottom,Right,Left programmatically and that is the code I was searching here but with no avail